# Props being passed as null (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'))

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { TaskLists } from "./TaskLists";
import { Daycard } from "./daycard";
import { getTasks, deleteTask } from "../api/task.api";

export function TaskManager() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadTasks() {
      const res = await getTasks();
      setTasks(res.data);
    }
    loadTasks();
  }, []);

  const removeTask = async (id) => {
    await deleteTask(id);
    setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TaskLists tasks={tasks} removeTask={removeTask} />
      <Daycard tasks={tasks} removeTask={removeTask} />
    </div>
  );
}


import React from "react";
import { TaskCard } from "./TaskCard";

export function TaskLists({ tasks, removeTask }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <TaskCard
          key={task.id}
          task={task}
          onDelete={() => removeTask(task.id)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

 import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { TaskCard } from "./TaskCard";
import { useState } from "react";

export function Daycard({ tasks, removeTask, hashv }) {
  let b = 0;
  const [hash, setHash] = useState(hashv);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (b === 0) {
      navigate(`/tasks-create?hash=${hash}`);
      console.log(`the hash is ${hash}`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      onClick={handleClick}
      className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark flex-grow-1"
      style={{ height: "auto" }}
    >
      {tasks.map((task) => {
        if (task.hash === hash) {
          b = 1;
          return (
            <TaskCard
              key={task.id}
              task={task}
              onDelete={() => removeTask(task.id)}
            />
          );
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

the first one is the parent component and the others are the children why I am getting the error:

TaskLists.jsx:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
at TaskLists (TaskLists.jsx:7:14)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)

I think the issue is because the initial API call to fetch tasks might not have completed by the time these child components are rendered.

Comment: in loadTasks > res.data is not an array, use Array.isArray(res?.data) ? res.data : []

Comment: @MikeSouto I am still getting the error

Comment: something is changing tasks to undefined. if it is an array, even it is empty, array.map should not return an error

Answer (score 1):

You have to do null-exception handler for every data management.

I add code below.

```
async function loadTasks() {
  const res = await getTasks();
  //console.log(res) and check your response here.
  setTasks(Array.isArray(res) ? res : [res]);    
     //res can be null, also res is not null but res.data can be null.
}
loadTasks();
```

Also, In TaskLists,

```
export function TaskLists({ tasks = [], removeTask }) {
....
```

I hope my answer can help you even a little

Comment: I am not getting the error now, my problem now is that no taskcard is getting displayed

Comment: that means result is not array. Did you do `console.log(res)` in where I adviced? If so, show me the result. ok?

Comment: yep, it is getting posted into the API but not being rendered

Comment: {hash: '1', title: '1', description: 'q', date: '0001-01-01T01:01'}

Comment: Just a minute, I will change my answer.  So is that data is one of array you wanted?

Comment: One more question. Is that data is `res` or `res.data`?

Comment: that data is res

Comment: I changed my answer. But I don't understand why response is JSON, not Array.I think your server side has problem.

Comment: At least, if the total card count is 1 the response should be `[{hash: '1', title: '1', description: 'q', date: '0001-01-01T01:01'}]` , right?

Comment: Still task card component is not being rendered

Comment: but you said `res` is `{hash: '1', title: '1', description: 'q', date: '0001-01-01T01:01'}`?

Comment: can you share total project?

Comment: res is not being shown in the console

Comment: here is the total project: https://github.com/SamLCris/calendar_app/blob/master/client/src/components/daycard.jsx

Comment: that version is without the parent component TaskManger()

Answer (score 0):

When rendering your component you can check if tasks has some value.if yes render it and else if not don't.

```
  return (
    <div>
{tasks.length > 0 ?
      <>
      <TaskLists tasks={tasks} removeTask={removeTask} />
      <Daycard tasks={tasks} removeTask={removeTask} />
      </>
:null}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error, you should ensure that the tasks prop is not null or undefined before trying to map over it. You can do this by adding a conditional check to ensure that tasks` is not empty before rendering the components.

```
 <div>
      {tasks.length > 0 ? (
        <>
          <TaskLists tasks={tasks} removeTask={removeTask} />
          <Daycard tasks={tasks} removeTask={removeTask} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <p>No tasks available</p>
      )}
    </div>
```